# <<operator is only printing an empty line

Tags: c++, linked-list

In main the list prints out using the insertion operator, but all that I get is an empty line. Not sure why. Is it that there is nothing being stored in the list even when you use the set_coefficient? Any other critiquing is welcome. Thanks

here's the driver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "polynomial.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
Polynomial* poly = new Polynomial();    

poly->set_coefficient(3,2);

poly->set_coefficient(0,2);

poly->set_coefficient(3,1);

cout << "trying to print data" << endl;
cout << *poly << endl;    
return 0;   
}
```

Here's the header:

```
#ifndef _POLYNOMIAL_H_
#define _POLYNOMIAL_H_

#include <iostream>

class Polynomial {

public:

struct PolyNode {
    int coefficient, degree;
    struct PolyNode* next;      
    PolyNode(int c, int d, PolyNode* n): coefficient(c),degree(d),next(n){}
};

PolyNode* firstTerm;
Polynomial(): firstTerm(0) {} 

struct PolyNode* get_first(){
    return firstTerm;
}


//makes the term with degree d have a coefficient of c
void set_coefficient(int c, int d);     

~Polynomial();  

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Polynomial& p);          
};

#endif
```

Here's the implementation:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

void Polynomial::set_coefficient(int c, int d){
PolyNode* start = firstTerm;
if(c != 0 && firstTerm == 0)    
    firstTerm = new PolyNode(c,d,NULL);
else{   
    cout << "Entered set_coefficient()" << endl;
    while(start->degree != d && start->next != NULL){
        cout << "Inside set_coefficient() while loop" << endl;          
        start = start->next;        
    }       
    if(c != 0 && start == 0)    
        start = new PolyNode(c,d,0);
    else if(c!= 0 && start != 0)
        start->coefficient = c;
    else if(c == 0){
        cout << "deleting a term" << endl;          
        delete start;
    }
}   
    cout << "Leaving set_coefficient()" << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Polynomial& p){
Polynomial::PolyNode* start = p.firstTerm;  
for(unsigned int i = 0; start->next != 0; i++){
    o << "Term " << i << "'s coefficient is: " << start->coefficient << " degree is: " << start->degree << endl << flush;
    start = start->next;
}   
return o;
}
```

Comment: why are you using `struct PolyNode` instead of `class PolyNode` in the header file?

Comment: @hexa: Perhaps because he only needs it as a POD. Structs and classes are the same exact thing, the only difference being that structs have public as the default visibility modifier and classes having private as the default. It saves a line of typing, and it self documents that the data structure is a POD.

Comment: @MikeB I see. It's just weird for me, a C programmer, seeing a struct with a constructor :P, thanks tho'

Comment: Next time use a proper title for your post...

Comment: why are you writing (and now debugging) your own linked list implementation? wouldn't a wrapper around std::list (or std::vector) suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     if(c != 0 && start == 0)
        start = new PolyNode(c,d,0);
    else if(c!= 0 && start != 0)
        start->coefficient = c;
    else if(c == 0){
        cout << "deleting a term" << endl;
        delete start;
    }

if (c != 0 && start == 0) // this situation may occur ? you have already judged surrounding if

else if (c == 0) {
    cout << "deleting a term" << endl;
    delete start;      // that may be cause linkedList detach.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cout << "Entered set_coefficient()" << endl;
> while(start->degree != d && start->next != NULL){
>     cout << "Inside set_coefficient() while loop" << endl;          
>     start = start->next;        
> }       
> if(c != 0 && start == 0)    
>     start = new PolyNode(c,d,0);
> else if(c!= 0 && start != 0)
>     start->coefficient = c;
> else if(c == 0){
>     cout << "deleting a term" << endl;          
>     delete start;
> }
> ```

It appears you want a linked list, but you're neither creating nor removing links (`start->next`), only allocating memory.  Without setting up the links, there is no list.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably multiple bugs here :>

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Polynomial& p){
Polynomial::PolyNode* start = p.firstTerm;  
for(unsigned int i = 0; start->next != 0; i++){
```

this won't print the last PolyNode...